# How to get selected radio button value in Laravel

Tags: laravel-4, radio-button, return-value

Hi all how to get selected radio button value. I want to store values on my table where selected radio button.

My Controller code passing to View $result

```
        $result =     DB::table('table')
                                ->where('name', $name)
                                ->where('code', $code)
                                ->get();

        return  View::make('home.search_result')            
                       ->with('result', $result);
```

In my view code I had radio button.

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'BookingController@postValue',  'class'=>'well', 'method' => 'GET')) }}         
<table id="search" class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Code</th>                                                                                                              
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
        @foreach($result as $result)                                    
            <tr class="success">    
                <td>{{ Form::radio('result') }}
                <td>{{ $result->name}}</td>                 
                <td>{{ $result->code}}</td>                 
            </tr>                       
        @endforeach                           
    </tfoot>
</table>           

{{ Form::submit('Add', array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) }}         
{{ Form::close() }}
```

So I try to pass chechked radio button value to my postValue function when I click Add button.

Answer (score 9):

You need to give the radio button a value. All you've given it is a name.

```
<td>{{ Form::radio('result', $result->code) }}
```

Then in your controller that processes the form you can grab the value.

```
$result = Input::get('result');
```

Comment: Nice. Your code is working. But i had lot of value. I can put them array?

Comment: If you want to be able to select multiple you should be using a checkbox and the name would be `result[]`. Then `Input::get('result');` would contain an array of values.

Comment: No Checkbox is no need. I can select only one value. This one value is have multiple values inside. For example name, code, age, date time etc. You can see example image following link [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1zzn6kqf8q5d54x/ss.PNG)

Answer (score 3):

You need to give a name to the radio button.

Normal HTML : `<input name="sex" type="radio" value="male">`

Laravel : `{{ Form::radio('sex', 'male') }}`

```
Form::radio('name','value');
```

Laravel gets parameter for name and value.