# Laravel : how to check if a specific value was selected

Tags: php, laravel

I have a very newbie question in Laravel.

In the controller I want to create something like :

```
if ($Q_type = "specific Value selected by the end user in a radio button") 
{
    do an action
}
```

what is the syntax to check this specific value ?

Comment: I'm no an expert but: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23321294/how-to-get-selected-radio-button-value-in-laravel

Comment: `=` != `===`. `=` assigns from rigth to left, `===`or `==` compares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in the following way:

```
if(request()->Q_type == "blue") 
{
    return 'blue';
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I want to make it !== , what is the correct syntax ?