# Laravel, How to get data from form of radio buttons?

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel

I am just very confused about how to get data with radio buttons of my form. I basically want my radio buttons the give me a number of some type of `id(info_id)` of user. As an example;

```
{!! Form::radio('job_id', '1') !!}= will send info_id 1
{!! Form::radio('job_id', '2') !!}= will send info_id 2
{!! Form::radio('job_id', '3') !!}= will send info_id 3
{!! Form::radio('job_id', '4') !!}= will send info_id 4
```

So this `id` numbers will create `info_id` of the user. How should i create radio input forms, and how i will make my controller to create this `id` in user data as `info_id`. Can anyone give me a simple example about it please?

Comment: any ideas? I think it is something very easy but i just never used radio buttons in forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer this link -

[How to get selected radio button value in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23321294/how-to-get-selected-radio-button-value-in-laravel)

And in controller get radio button data in request check it like this -

```
dd($request->job_id); //you will get job_id's selected value
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: yeah i get the value! thanks for this. just now i cant put this value into job_id of the user.

Comment: which code i should use to create it? ohh it made me tired.. i do like this but still its not working, i mean i dont see the value in job_id of the user:

$input = $request->job_id;
User::create($input);

Comment: also user's job_id has these index()->unsigned()->nullable(); in migrations. maybe i thought problem may be because of these ?

Comment: im getting this error : (1/1) FatalThrowableError
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::create() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\X-GOTL\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php on line 1374

Comment: can you please share your User tables columns ? And for inserting data pass data like this -  User::create(['job_id' => $input]);